# How can I make Get.isDarkMode change the icon?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I can change the theme in my app, but I have a problem when using `Get.isDarkMode` it doesn't listen when I try to change the `text color` or I try to change the `icon`

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class ThemeService {
  final _box = GetStorage();
  final _key = 'isDarkMode';

  ThemeMode get theme => _loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;

  bool _loadThemeFromBox() => _box.read(_key) ?? false;

  _saveThemeToBox(bool isDarkMode) => _box.write(_key, isDarkMode);

  void switchTheme() {
    Get.changeThemeMode(_loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
    _saveThemeToBox(!_loadThemeFromBox());
  }
}
```

```
 IconButton( icon: Icon(Get.isDarkMode ? Icons.dark_mode_outlined : Icons.light_mode_outlined) , onPressed: (){
            ThemeService().switchTheme();
          },)
```

Comment: Can you recheck and include `getx` if you are using it

Comment: I am trying I have used `setState` inside the button and it worked but it works intermittently..
`IconButton( icon: Icon( Get.isDarkMode ? Icons.dark_mode_outlined : Icons.light_mode_outlined) ,onPressed:(){
ThemeService().switchTheme();
setState(() {
});`

Answer (score 0):

use context.isDarkMode bofore use Get.isDarkMode

> context.isDarkMode

for example [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsgE0.png)